# nested for loops in stata

Tags: for-loop, stata

I am having trouble to understand why a for loop construction does not work. I am not really used to for loops so I apologize if I am missing something basic. Anyhow, I appreciate any piece of advice you might have.

I am using a party level dataset from the [parlgov project](http://www.parlgov.org/). I am trying to create a variable which captures how many times a party has been in government before the current observation. Time is important, the counter should be zero if a party has not been in government before, even if after the observation period it entered government multiple times. Parties are nested in countries and in cabinet dates.

The code is as follows:

```
use "http://eborbath.github.io/stackoverflow/loop.dta", clear //to get the data
```

if this does not work, I also uploaded in a csv format, try:

```
import delimited "http://eborbath.github.io/stackoverflow/loop.csv", bindquote(strict) encoding(UTF-8) clear
```

The loop should go through each country-specific cabinet date, identify the previous observation and check if the party has already been in government. This is how far I have got:

```
gen date2=cab_date
gen gov_counter=0    
levelsof country, local(countries) // to get to the unique values in countries    
foreach c of local countries{
    preserve // I think I need this to "re-map" the unique cabinet dates in each country
    keep if country==`c'
    levelsof cab_date, local(dates) // to get to the unique cabinet dates in individual countries
    restore        
    foreach i of local dates {
        egen min_date=min(date2) // this is to identify the previous cabinet date
        sort country party_id date2     
        bysort country party_id: replace gov_counter=gov_counter+1 if date2==min_date & cabinet_party[_n-1]==1 // this should be the counter
        bysort country: replace date2=. if date2==min_date // this is to drop the observation which was counted
        drop min_date //before I restart the nested loop, so that it again gets to the minimum value in `dates'
}
}
```

The code works without an error, but it does not do the job. Evidently there's a mistake somewhere, I am just not sure where.

BTW, it's a specific application of a problem I super often encounter: how do you count frequencies of distinct values in a multilevel data structure? This is slightly more specific, to the extent that "time matters", and it should not just sum all encounters. Let me know if you have an easier solution for this.

Thanks!

Comment: I would strip this down to an MCVE (Google if necessary). I don't want to download a big dataset and work out which details are important.

Comment: (continued) My instinct is that no loops whatsoever are needed here. The answer by @the.ge already points that way. Is it complete?

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Next time I make sure to post an MCVE dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your loop is that it does not keep the replaced gov_counter after the loop. However, there is a much easier solution I'd recommend:

```
 sort country party_id cab_date
 by country party_id: gen gov_counter=sum(cabinet_party[_n-1])
```

This sorts the data into groups and then creates a sum by group, always up to (but not including) the current observation.

Comment: Thanks, it is much simpler and does what I needed

Comment: This goes to the heart of the problem. But I think it's wrong on diagnosing the problem. The variable `gov_counter` is not only kept, it is changed repeatedly on the inner loop.

Comment: That is what I meant - sorry, I was unspecific.

Answer (score 1):

I would start here. I have stripped the comments so that we can look at the code. I have made some tiny cosmetic alterations.

```
 foreach i of local dates {
        egen min_date = min(date2) 
        sort country party_id date2     
        bysort country party_id: replace gov_counter=gov_counter+1 ///
             if date2 == min_date & cabinet_party[_n-1] == 1 
        bysort country: replace date2 = . if date2 == min_date 
        drop min_date 
 }
```

This loop includes no reference to the loop index `i` defined in the `foreach` statement. So, the code is the same and completely unaffected by the loop index. The variable `min_date` is just a constant for the dataset and the same each time around the loop. What does depend on how many times the loop is executed is how many times the counter is incremented.

The fallacy here appears to be a false analogy with constructs in other software, in which a loop automatically spawns separate calculations for different values of a loop index.

It's not illegal for loop contents never to refer to the loop index, as is easy to see

```
forval j = 1/3 {
   di "Hurray"
}
```

produces

```
Hurray
Hurray
Hurray
```

But if you want different calculations for different values of the loop index, that has to be explicit.

Comment: thank you for your extensive and informative feedback; I really appreciate it!  I am just wondering how to set it up in a way to index the loop value.